# Testing mirror to default SQLite database django

Tags: django, sqlite

I am trying to set up some testing on my Django application. I have used a database mirror for the test database. When I try to run few test it appears the data from 'default database' is not available in the mirror test database.

```
'default': { #'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'OPTIONS':{
            'timeout': 180,
        },
        'TEST_MIRROR': 'default'


    },
```

my tests:

```
data_school = DataSchool.objects.all()
self.assertTrue(data_school.exists())
```

I am confused, the test_mirrors configured by the database administrator as a read replica of default database and in theory any data in default database should be available for test? But When I run the tests I don't see any 'Fixtures' loading. Should I specify which fixtures to load if I have more than one fixtures? If I have any configuration errors  please do let know. Thanks

Comment: Django does not automatically load fixtures for apps with migrations. If you need to load fixtures, you need to do so in your test setup. Django itself has moved away from fixtures and uses the ORM to create test data. I'm not sure you understand the `TEST_MIRROR` setting. It does not allow you to mirror a live database, it allows you to mark one test database as a replica of another test database. This allows you to recreate a master/slave setup in your tests, but it doesn't allow you to use live data in your test databases.

Comment: In your code snippet, you've configured `default` as it's own `TEST_MIRROR`. That's wrong. Explain better what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I indeed had confused with TEST: {'MIRROR': 'default'}. Thanks for pointing it.